# Porque o acesso a uma Session dentro de um ActionFilter está se comportando desta maneira

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

### Saudação a todos.

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em Asp.NET MVC5 e encontrei um seguinte problema:

A aplicação precisa que eu efetue o login do usuário a partir de qualquer tela que ele acessar via browser. Para diminuir a quantidade de linhas de códigos em minhas views criei um **ActionFilter** que vai servir tanto para validar o login quanto para popular as Sessions que preciso manter no meu site para o funcionamento adequado do solicitante.

Seguindo esta lógica, ao fazer o primeiro acesso ao site as sessões são preenchidas de maneira correta, até ai nenhum problema, entretanto quando atualizamos por exemplo o perfil do usuário para garantir mais acessos ao mesmo percebemos que as sessões não estavam sendo atualizadas automaticamente entre a navegação das telas (o ActionFilter é configurado para rodar antes da execução das ações). Percebendo isso, pensei em um workaround, criando um botão que chamaria uma ação para atualizar essas sessões e tudo ok, certo? Errado!

Quando utilizo por exemplo:

```
public ActionResult AtualizaPerfil()
{
...
HttpContext.Session["PerfilUsuario"] = idPerfil;
...
}
```

dentro da minha action eu atribuo um valor a sessão e ao final da action eu efetuo um redirect para uma view `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");` que tem o ActionFilter vinculado `[ControleAcessoActionFilter]`.

Dentro do ActionFilter, eu tenho o Método a seguir:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
...
if (HttpContext.Current.Session["PerfilUsuario"] == null)
   {
       filterContext.HttpContext.Session.Add("PerfilUsuario", idPerfil);
   }
...
}
```

Eis que chegamos no problema, a Session["PerfilUsuario"] da minha view não atribuiu o valor a minha HttpContext.Current.Session["PerfilUsuario"], achei bem estranho uma vez que ambas tem origem igual seguindo a lógica deste post aqui do [StackOverflow Internacional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940742/difference-between-session-and-httpcontext-current-session).

Alguém teria alguma outra explicação para este caso?

Comment: Você não está trabalhando com contextos diferentes?
`if (HttpContext.Current.Session["PerfilUsuario"] == null)` e `filterContext.HttpContext.Session`?

Comment: Acredito que não @LeandroAngelo, uma vez que o httpContext teoricamente é herdado pelo filterContext uma vez que este recebe toda a parametrização da action antes da mesma ser executada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Bom dia Pessoal!

Encontrei a solução no final da sexta-feira.
Pelo que entendi sobre esta questão de sessões e actionFilters, se a criação da Sessão for feita dentro da `actionFilter`, não posso executar `Abandon()`, `Clear()` ou `RemoveAll()` para as sessões em alguma action de alguma view, a Sessão que será validada na actionFilter ficara em um context/instância diferente da action para as sessões (parece bizarro, mas isso aconteceu mesmo no meu VS2017).